# Unable to add net.tcp as service reference

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, metadata, nettcpbinding

I have created a net.tcp WCF service like so:

```
const string tcpUri = "net.tcp://localhost:9038";
var netTcpHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(DashboardService), new Uri(tcpUri));
netTcpHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDashboardService), new NetTcpBinding(), 
                                                             "/dashboard");

netTcpHost.Open();

Console.WriteLine("Hosted at {0}. Hit any key to shut down", tcpUri);
Console.ReadKey();

netTcpHost.Close();
```

Here is my `IDashboardService` and `DashboardSerivce` definitions:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDashboardService
{
    [OperationContract]
    PositionDashboard Loader();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class DashboardService : IDashboardService
{
    public PositionDashboard Loader()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, when I try to connect to the service with the WCF Test Client, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://localhost:9038/dashboard
The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your 
message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying 
network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:04:59.9890000'.    An existing 
connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is explicitly mentioning **"Cannot obtain Metadata..."** so it would be worth checking that you have a TCP Mex Endpoint. It should look something like this in config:

```xml
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Alternatively, if you you want to do then you need to reference **System.ServiceModel.Discovery** and then your code should look like this:

```
const string tcpUri = "net.tcp://localhost:9038";
using (var netTcpHost = new WebServiceHost(
    typeof(DashboardService),
    new Uri(tcpUri)))
{
    netTcpHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior());
    netTcpHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
        typeof(IMetadataExchange),
        MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(),
        "mex");
    netTcpHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
        typeof(IDashboardService),
        new NetTcpBinding(),
        "dashboard");

    netTcpHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
    netTcpHost.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());

    netTcpHost.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Hosted at {0}. Hit any key to shut down", tcpUri);
    Console.ReadLine();

    netTcpHost.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm creating it all programatically (ie no app/web.config). How would I do that programatically?

Comment: I get an error when I tried that: The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service Services.DashboardService. Add a serivceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try tomorrow and let you know